# How to run Ubuntu Server VM as a internet (not local) web server through OS X host

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS VM on VirtualBox on a OS X 10.7.5 (Lion) host. The host has a static IP address, and I can use it as a web server, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the VM Ubuntu server as a web server instead. What are the network configurations I need so that port 80 is accessible through the VM?

Comment: I have a similar question as yours. I have solved half of it. See my question and answer here. http://superuser.com/questions/527507/use-ubuntu-12-10-server-vm-as-web-server-for-development-on-mac-os-x-via-virtual/527508#527508 Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think with the setup you propose I should be able to use NAT to use my host address on a port >1024, which is certainly a step in the right direction.

Comment: you are welcome. Do let me know at my solution if it is not working for whatever reasons.